# Access the nth element of an object in Python

Tags: python

Here's the json

```
{u'skeleton_horde': 2, u'baby_dragon': 3, u'valkyrie': 5, u'chr_witch': 1, u'lightning': 1, u'order_volley': 6, u'building_inferno': 3, u'battle_ram': 2}
```

I'm trying to make the list look like this

```
skeleton_horde baby_dragon valkyrie lightning order_volley building_inferno
```

Here's the python

```
print(x['right']['troops'])
```

There's surprisingly no documentation on how to get the n element of an object (not array). I tried:

```
print(x['right']['troops'][1])
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I assume you're dealing with a Python dictionary rather than a JSON file?

Comment: There is no nth element. Dicts are semantically unordered.

Comment: @user2357112 Not semantically, they're ordered by key hashes.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake: They're not even ordered by hash values. Hashes are involved, but even dicts with the same keys and the same key hashes can show up in different orders.

Comment: [Example.](http://ideone.com/BIjiFF)

Comment: Just out of curiousity - why are two of the elements missing?

Comment: @JonClements I wonder if the OP simply didn't bother with all of them? After all, they're looking for a way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want to extract the keys:

```
x['right']['troops']
```

Then you want to join them with spaces interspersed

```
' '.join(x['right']['troops'])
```

This will be in a different order than what you have, though, since Python dictionaries are unordered.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `dict.keys()` to a get a list* of the key values of the dict:

```
print(list(x['right']['troops'].keys()))
```

*It's [actually a view](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), in Python 3. It would be a list in Python 2.

Comment: Thank you! I'm used to javascript and iterating across the array :)

Comment: View or list depends on the Python version. Given the `u` tags on the Unicode strings, I'm guessing Python 2.

Comment: No need to call `keys()`, you can simply apply `list` to a `dict`: `list({'a':1})` results in `['a']`.

Comment: @DanD. is absolutely correct. I tend to go for `keys()` for parallelism to `values()` and `items()` and clarity (to myself, at least). If you need every ounce of speed out of your interpreter, avoiding the extra lookup and call might help, (but I bet the list constructor does it anyway...).

Answer (score 2):

There's no way of getting the nth item in a `dict`ionary (perhaps you've conflated Python dicts with JavaScript objects) for the simple reason that they are unordered.

There is however a type of dictionary that does maintain the order of its keys, aptly named `OrderedDict`.

### Solution

As another commenter pointed out, there *is* a solution to your problem, but it still won't give you the keys in the order of definition:

```
' '.join(obj['right']['troops'])
```

### Note

In a recent version of CPython (3.6), dictionary keys are indeed ordered. I'm not sure if I'd rely on implementation-specific behaviour, or whether you even need to order the keys in this case, but it's good to know. Props to @ScottColby for pointing this out to me!

Comment: In Python 3.6, [dictionaries are now ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6) and this may even be guaranteed in python 3.7. Just another reason to drop Python 2 :)

Comment: \*small error in my comment: In **C**Python 3.6. It's not yet guaranteed in other implementations.

Comment: I'm aware. I checked out the link. I assume you noticed the edit?

Comment: yes, I do see that now. I just wanted to correct my comment as well--it was your edit that reminded me :)